# Excel how to keep fraction as fraction 5/5 not 1 or 0/5 not 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, formula, fractions

I have a sheet that counts the positive cells in a range, and all the non blank cells in the same range. It displays the result as a fraction. I would like to stop excel from displaying fractions as whole numbers, e.g., 5/5 not 1, 0/2 not 0, 0/5 not 0. Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

The formula in column F is as follows: =COUNTIF(A2:E2,">0")/COUNTIF(A2:E2,"<>")

Column G shows how I would like the results displayed.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you treat all as fractions of `5`? Would make life a lot easier when you custom numberformat everything to `?/5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the `/` in quotes and concatenate with `&`.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E2,">0")&"/"&COUNTIF(A2:E2,"<>")
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then it is treated as text.

Comment: Because `5/5` *is* text, not a number.

Comment: It's an improper fraction equivalent to 1 but still a number.

Comment: It is text according to Excel. If your denominator is constant then you can use a custom number format as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956132/excel-how-to-keep-fraction-as-fraction-5-5-not-1-or-0-5-not-0/65956221#comment116615509_65956132) by @JvdV. Otherwise... this is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
You need to format the cell/column where you get the result of your formula. Let's say it is Cell "B6". Choose "Fraction" in the "Number" section of the "Home" ribbon. Right-click your mouse and choose "Format cells". Go to "Custom" and make your own format. It can be something like this "???/???" or like this "###/###".
I hope it will help you.